# NsLookup print out cleanup

Tags: python, string, line-breaks

Hello how do I remove the `\r\` and `\n\` the `\r\n\r\n'`?

```
b'Server:  fe503bde43df\r\nAddress:  10.0.0.243\r\n\r\n'
```

I have tried a few thing but no luck..

```
import os
import subprocess
import socket
import datetime
import re
import csv
import pprint



with open('NewData.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for i in csvfile:
        proc = subprocess.check_output(['nslookup', i])
        
        print(proc.strip("`\n", "\r"))
```

replace option...

Comment: The `\r` is a CR char, you can just apply `.replace(b'\r', b'')` to remove it from your *byte string*.

Comment: Thank you so much still learning..

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all carriage returns from your byte string using

```py
.replace(b'\r', b'')
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Hsgg5H):

```py
print( b'Server: fe503bde43df\r\nAddress: 10.0.0.243\r\n\r\n'.replace(b'\r', b'') )
# => b'Server: fe503bde43df\nAddress: 10.0.0.243\n\n'
```